# Get related rows in the same table?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, phpmyadmin

I'm struggling with this one. What I need is to Select a row AND other rows from the same table that are related. Here is an example of the table:

```
table
key    |    value    |    related
=================================
1      |    omg      |    0
2      |    lol      |    0
3      |    rofl     |    2
4      |    barfoo   |    0
5      |    foo      |    0
6      |    bar      |    0
...
20000  |    haha     |    2
```

(where the related "2" is the row key for "lol")

So in the case that i do (not simultaneously) either this:

```
SELECT * FROM table Where value='lol'
```

or this

```
SELECT * FROM table Where value='rofl'
```

or this

```
SELECT * FROM table Where value='haha'
```

it should return:

```
key    |    value    |    related
=================================
2      |    lol      |    0
3      |    rofl     |    2
20000  |    haha     |    2
```

Any ideas guys?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Select * From table t 
Where Exists 
   (Select * From Table
    where value = @theValue
       and valueKey in (t.ValueKey, t.related))
```